# I have a .sid image but can't figure out the CRS

Tags: qgis

There is a .map file:

```
OziExplorer Map Data File Version 2.2
Tiritir_2.sid
C:\OziExplorer\Maps\Islands\Tiritir_2.sid
1 ,Map Code,
Geodetic Datum 1949,WGS 84,   0.0000,   0.0000,WGS 84
Reserved 1
Reserved 2
Magnetic Variation,,,E
Map Projection,(NZG) New Zealand Grid,PolyCal,No,AutoCalOnly,No,BSBUseWPX,No
```

my best guess is NZGD49 North Island but when I use this projection the data from the GPS does not match.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about EPSG:27200? The others are more or less locally adopted, but the file info does not name any.

How much offset do you get?

Comment: I have selected a known point (the start of a track) which I can identify on both the layer from the GPS and the raster layer (whose CRS is uncertain).

Comment: Oops I spent to long editing the response after hitting return and accidentally posting.  

Offsets are of the order of 500000,900000.

I do have output of mrsidinfo for the original sid file if that would be useful.  I am coming to the conclusion that my best bet is to try and find out what and who produced the original file.  The joys of volunteer projects :)

Comment: You could try one of the other NZGD systems available, or just re-georefrence the raster file upon the known points you have.

Comment: It is EPSG:27200.  What confused me was that when looking in the QGIS CRS selector 27200 is listed under Geographic Coordinate Systems and all the other ones that I was looking at were under NZ Map Grid so I did not find it until I used the filter at the top.  Doh!  everything matches nicely now.

I also found this site extremely useful: http://spatialreference.org/ I found it by searching for 27200 when I could not find it in QGIS.  It enabled me to match the data I got from mrsidinfo with the EPSG #
Thanks very much Andre,

Comment: Just to clearify: The geografic CRS called NZGD49 has EPSG:4279 and uses lat/lon, then you have the projected EPSG:27200 filed under NewZealand Map Grid, and the rest filed under Transverse Mercator. Not very intuitive, but you can saerch for 'NZ' or any EPSG number in Qgis Filter box.