# How to find out projection code for the sid file?

Tags: coordinate-system, mrsid

I have a miami.sid file and miami.sdw and miami.sid.aux.xml files.

How to find out the projection code? This question is similar to:

[I have a .sid image but can't figure out the CRS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48765/i-have-a-sid-image-but-cant-figure-out-the-crs)

```
GDALInfo output:
----------------
Driver: MrSID/Multi-resolution Seamless Image Database (MrSID)
Files: C:\Users\Miami_25ft.sid
       C:\Users\Miami_25ft.sdw
       C:\Users\Miami_25ft.sid.aux.xml
Size is 112000, 60000
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (876995.250000000000000,539495.000000000000000)
Pixel Size = (0.250000000000000,-0.250000000000000)

Metadata:
  IMAGE__ENCODING_APPLICATION=GeoExpress 8.0.0.3065
  IMAGE__FORMAT=MrSID/MG3
  IMAGE__INPUT_FILE_SIZE=20165006292.000000
  IMAGE__INPUT_FORMAT=TIFF w/ World File
  IMAGE__INPUT_NAME=D:\11715_7_color_adjusted\0.25 Ft\10NE.tif,  D:\11715_7_color_adjusted\0.25 Ft\10NW.tif, D:\11715_7_color_adjusted\0.25 Ft\10SE.tif, D:\11715_7_color_adjusted\0.25 Ft\10SW.tif, D:\11715_7_color_adjusted\0.25 Ft\11NE.tif, D:\11715_7_color_adjusted\0.25 Ft\11NW.tif, D:\11715_7_color_adjusted\0.25 Ft\11SE.tif, D:\11715_7_color_adjusted\0.25 Ft\11SW.tif, D:\11715_7_color_adjusted\0.25 Ft\12NE.tif, D:\11715_7_color_adjusted\0.25 Ft\12NW.tif, D:\11715_7_color_adjusted\0.25 Ft\12SE.tif,  
.....
.....
D:\11715_7_color_adjusted\0.25 Ft\8SE.tif, D:\11715_7_color_adjusted\0.25 Ft\9NE.tif, D:\11715_7_color_adjusted\0.25 Ft\9NW.tif, D:\11715_7_color_adjusted\0.25 Ft\9SE.tif, D:\11715_7_color_adjusted\0.25 Ft\9SW.tif
  IMAGE__LTI_ESDK_VERSION=8.0.0.3065.Bob_3062_br win64-vc8/Release                              
  IMAGE__MODIFICATIONS=COMPRESSED EMBEDDED MOSAICKED
  PShop__ImageResources=
  VERSION=MG3
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL

Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  876998.250,  539499.000) 
Lower Left  (  876998.250,  524499.000) 
Upper Right (  904998.250,  539499.000) 
Lower Right (  904998.250,  524499.000) 
Center      (  890998.250,  531999.000) 

Band 1 Block=1024x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=143.114, StdDev=49.379
  Overviews: 56000x30000, 28000x15000, 14000x7500, 7000x3750, 3500x1875, 1750x938, 875x469, 438x235, 219x118, 110x59

Band 2 Block=1024x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=145.812, StdDev=46.856
  Overviews: 56000x30000, 28000x15000, 14000x7500, 7000x3750, 3500x1875, 1750x938, 875x469, 438x235, 219x118, 110x59

Band 3 Block=1024x128 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=141.074, StdDev=47.739
  Overviews: 56000x30000, 28000x15000, 14000x7500, 7000x3750, 3500x1875, 1750x938, 875x469, 438x235, 219x118, 110x59
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's in NAD 1983 (or one of its re-adjustments) State Plane Florida East (US survey feet).

To generalize an answer, other useful information is--

1. Data source? Particularly governmental agencies will state somewhere
   what coordinate reference systems are in use.
2. Data location? In this
   case, the name of the file was a clue. With vector data, attribute
   information can sometimes provide information.

How to figure it out yourself?

1. Do some research to figure out what coordinate reference systems (CRS) are used in the data's location.
2. Add some data that you know has 'good' CRS to a mapping software package. Enable the on-the-fly projection and set the target CRS to the ones you found in the previous step.
3. If you can get the area of interest to display similar coordinate values as your problematic data, you've likely found the correct CRS.
4. Optionally, add the problematic data with an 'unknown' CRS. It should correctly overlay (because the on-the-fly projection can't do anything to it).
5. Define the CRS.

Comment: NAD 1983 is not working :(.

Comment: More details! Extents and CRS of the layer you're comparing it against. What's the offset?

Comment: NAD 1983 with 'Feet' as unit worked. Thanks:)